# scanning user input in python

Tags: python

```
direction = input("enter a direction: ")
if direction != "quit" and direction != "go north" and direction != "go south" and direction != "go east" and direction != "go west" and direction != "go up" and direction != "go down" and direction != "look":
    print ("please enter in the following format, go (north,east,south,west,up,down)")

elif direction == "quit":
    print ("OK ... but a small part of you may never leave until you have personally saved Muirfieland from the clutches of evil .. Bwahahahahahah (sinister laugh) ... the game should then end.")

elif direction == "look":
    print ("You see nothing but endless void stretching off in all directions ...")

else:
    print ("You wander of in the direction of " + direction)
```

i need to know how to do this in python.
i need to scan user inputs first 2 letters
for example

```
i = user_input
#user inputs go ayisgfdygasdf
```

i need it to be able to scan the user input, check if the first 2 letters are go, and if they are go but it doesnt recognise the second word which in this case is "ayisgfdygasdf" then to print "sorry, i cant do that"

Comment: not really, if the program recognises the first word which is "go" but doesnt recognise the second word then python prints "sorry, i cant do that"

Answer (score 1):

He could also try using:

```
    directions.split()
```

But it may require to use try/except in some cases.

For more information about split and methods try using:

```
    dir(directions)
```

to see what methods object directions have

or:

```
    help(directions.split)
```

to see help about a specific method (in this case method split of object directions)

Comment: `.split()` itself will always work as long as `directions` actually is a string; no need to catch exceptions there. However, you do then need to worry about how many items are in the result :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access characters of a string in python by index using the [] notation. You can check the first two character in a string by typing user_input[:2]. This code will include all characters up to, but not including the index typed. So this notation will include user_input[0] and user_input[1]. You can then check if user_input[:2] is equal to 'go' or not, and continue from there.

Hope this helped.

Comment: i got this to work, but i got another problem if you look at my code
for example if user input is "go north"
it will print "you wonder off in the direction of go north"
i would like to remove the "go " from the user input, how would i do this?

Comment: use this direction[3:] for printing, this will use a subarray from the third character on.

Comment: that's correct, user_input[3:] will contain the substring from character 3 to end of string (in this example, it would include the space character) user_input[4:] would exclude the space character if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try using:

```
direction = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

It may require you to ctrl+D after you are done but you will be able to capture so much more.

Also, to get the subarray you can then you can even check:

```
direction[:2] != "go"
```

or alternatively, for more readable code:

```
if not direction.startswith("go"):
```

Also I'd recommend, for making your code more readable,

```
defined_direction = frozenset(["quit", "go north", "go south"])
if( direction not in defined_direction):
   print "please enter...."
```

Comment: No prob, I just answered on another comment that you still had a question about using the last item of the "go ". Let me know if that answer is clear. :)

Comment: What exactly does `sys.stdin.readlines()` get you that `sys.stdin` doesn't? Or, for that matter, calling `input` in a loop? Other than the downside that it requires you to hit ^D after you're done, or ^Z on Windows, and it may not work with some IDEs, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You can index the individual characters of your input:

```
if direction[:2] == "go":
    print "Sorry, I can't do that."
```

However, trying assign an if-else branch to each possible input is typically a bad choice... It becomes difficult to maintain very quickly.

A cleaner approach in this case might be to define a dictionary with valid input as follows:

```
input_response = {"quit":"OK ... but", "go north": "You wander off north", \
                  "go south": "You wander off south"} # etc
```

You could then re-write your code to something like:

```
try:
    print input_response[direction]
except KeyError:
    if direction[:2] == "go":
        print "Sorry, I can't do that."
    else:
        print ("please enter in the following format...")
```